# Overlap table cells in HTML with margins

Tags: html, html-table, overlay, cell, overlap

I'm trying to do an HTML email that have columns overlapped. No problems to do this with divs, but need to do it with tables and I didn't played with tables in years!

[image]

I need the green col to be displaced from top and overflow on bottom of the row.
The  blue row will have a background image and the green col will be a solid background color.
I've tried nesting a new table inside the row and doing the row taller than the background image, but I want to know if is there any other solution.

This is what I currently have:

http://jsfiddle.net/mdzvvx3q/

```
<table width="800" border="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td height="98" colspan="2" style="background-color: #efefef;"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr height="400" style="background-color: #f0c;">
    <td colspan="2">
        <table height="400" width="800" border="0" cellspacing="0">
          <tr>
            <td height="100" colspan="2">Some text here</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td width="500" height="278"></td>
            <td width="300" style="background-color: #0fc;">More text here</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
    </td>
  <tr>
    <td height="98" colspan="2" style="background-color: #efefef;"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Would you be kind enough to post your HTML code in a working fiddle?

Comment: Ofcourse. Here is the code. Still empty but that's what I have.
http://jsfiddle.net/mdzvvx3q/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try below code.

I just created new Simplified HTML Structure and applied in-line style.

If you are trying to create email template. You should use in-line styles. Email template doesn't support internal & external style-sheets.

```
<table style="width: 500px;" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0">
    <tr style="background: #FF888A;">
        <td width="50%">First</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="background: #00C6FF;">
        <td colspan="2">First</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="background: #00C6FF;">First</td>
        <td style="background:#00FF95;">Overlay content</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="background: #00C6FF;">First</td>
        <td style="background:#00FF95;"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="background: #fff;">First</td>
        <td style="background:#00FF95;"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="background: #fff;">
        <td colspan="2">First</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="background: #FF888A;">
        <td colspan="2">First</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="background: #FF888A;">
        <td colspan="2">First</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

[**JSFIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/shanidkv/bk9zeaob/)

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATED ANSWER**

I had to edit this answer since you added a jsfiddler link. The below code should work and here's the updated jsfiddler link: http://jsfiddle.net/mdzvvx3q/3/

```
<table width="800" border="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td height="98" colspan="2" style="background-color: #efefef;"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr height="400" style="background-color: #f0c;">
    <td colspan="2">
        <table height="400" width="800" border="0" cellspacing="0">
          <tr>
            <td height="100" colspan="2">Some text here</td>
          </tr>
          <tr style="position: absolute; z-index: 1; bottom: 250px;">
            <td width="500" height="278"></td>
            <td width="300" style="background-color: #0fc;">More text here</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
    </td>
  <tr>
    <td height="98" colspan="2" style="background-color: #efefef;"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**ORIGINAL ANSWER BELOW**

You should be able to do this with CSS. Create a table with tr and td's and use position: absolute and z-index css properties.

Code is below and here's a live example: http://jsfiddle.net/luisbox/7x98qr7y/

HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr class="red">
        <td>First</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="blue">
        <td>second</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="overlap">
        <td>overlapped</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>blank</td>
    </tr>    
    <tr class="red">
        <td>second last</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="red">
        <td>last</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
table{
    width: 500px;
}

tr{
    width: 100%;
    height: 30px;
}

tr.red{
    background: red;
}

tr.blue{
    background: lightblue;
}

.overlap{
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 0;
    left: 300px;
    background: green;  
    width: 200px;
    height: 60px;
    color: white;
}
```

Comment: Created this jsfiddler before the post was edited with it's own fiddler

Comment: Never try to use absolute positioning on table cells or rows, or even inside table cells or rows. The results will have too many cross-browser and -device issues to solve them all. Instead, I'd suggest creating some divs inside one large table cell to mimic the desired behaviour.

Comment: I agree but looks like divs is not an option. Not sure why.